# Mongoose $push cannot push object into correct document

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema like this:

```
A = {
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    arrayA:[{
       _id,
       nestedArray: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]
    }],
    arrayB: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]
}
```

I would like to push an Object Id into nestedArray in specific arrayA object AND
arrayB should contains an specific Object Id by following code:

```
A.update({'arrayA._id': arrayAId, arrayB: {$in: [arrayContainsSomeArrayBIds]}},
{$push: {'arrayA.$.nestedArray': nestedArrayId}}, function(err) {
});
```

However, the Object Id is pushed into nestedArray of the last object in arrayA.
If `arrayB: {$in: [arrayContainsSomeArrayBIds]}` is removed, the Object Id can be pushed into correct object in arrayA.

mongoose version: 3.8.21

Can anyone help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible in `MongoDB` to update an a array element with the `positional` operator, when the query document contains references to other arrays apart from the one being updated.

The below code, contains reference to two arrays fields: `arrayA` and `arrayB`, when 
the update is issued on `arrayA`. This is invalid and would lead to undesired behavior.

```
A.update({'arrayA._id': arrayAId, arrayB: {$in: [arrayContainsSomeArrayBIds]}},
  {$push: {'arrayA.$.nestedArray': nestedArrayId}}, function(err) {
});
```

From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitation),

> **Only one** array field may appear in the query document. 
>   The query document should only contain a single condition on the array field
>   being projected. 
>   Multiple conditions may override each other
>   internally and lead to **undefined** behavior. 
>   **Under these requirements,
>   the following query is incorrect:**

```
 db.collection.find( { <array>: <value>, <someOtherArray>: <value2> },
                     { "<array>.$": 1 } )
```

The solution is to modify your code to fire two queries:

- Get the `_ids` of the documents, which match our condition.
- Then perform the update.

Sample Code flow:

```
A.find({'arrayA._id': arrayAId, arrayB: {$in: [arrayContainsSomeArrayBIds]}},
      function(err,data){
       data.forEach(function(doc){
           A.update({'arrayA._id': arrayAId,
                      "_id":doc._id},
                    {$push: {'arrayA.$.nestedArray': nestedArrayId}}, 
                    function(err) {
                    });
       })
});
```